# didReceiveLocalNotification: method works only if I press on notification banner

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, push-notification, uilocalnotification

I have some `UILocalNotifications` in my app. When I receive one while I am in the app or if I press on the notification banner from the block screen or when it appears, the `didReceiveLocalNotification` works just fine. However, if I do not use the application and if I press on the icon of it (not on the banner) after notification banner appeared, the `didReceiveLocalNotification` method is not being called.

What should I do in this case, if I still want receive information about local notifications? Can I get it somehow in the `applicationDidBecomeActive:` method for example?

Answer (score 0):

If you're app is completely shut down and you open it with a local notification, your local notification info will be passed into `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    UILocalNotification *localNotification = launchOptions[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];
    if (localNotification)
    {
        // Do whatever
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: true, I have this code in my project as well, but what if my app isn't shuted down and its just being in a background?

Comment: Then it should call `application:didReceiveLocalNotification:`

Comment: Yes, but somehow, it calls it only when I press on a banner or if I am being the the app but not if I directly press on the app icon.

Comment: Sorry, I finally understand. If the user presses on the app icon then they're not triggering the local notification, they're launching with no options. That's the way the OS is designed. You'll need to monitor another way to register that something was waiting for them to open the app, I guess.

Comment: Agree, but I can not find any possible solutions how to check for notifications in app delegate for now. Maybe any ideas?

Comment: Depends on what's triggering the local notification. E.g. if you want to send out a local notification 2 hours after the user closes the app, you can store in the user defaults a date that, if the app launches after that date, the notification is assumed to be received. It's impossible to generalise how to deal with this situation.